# Can't make it work reverse url for django with named args and view

Tags: django, url

I can't make work the get_absolute_url from the model to generate a proper url;

urls.py

```
url(r'^(P<cat>.*)/(?P<sub_cat>.*)/(?P<page>\d*)/$', 
        view = 'a.generic.views.article.list', 
        name = "article_list"),

url(r'^(?P<cat>.*)$', 
        view = 'a.generic.views.category.list_sub', 
        name = "category_list"),
```

models.py

```
@m.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.level == 2:
        return ('article_list', (), {
                        'cat': str(self.parent.seo_title), 
                        'sub_cat': str(self.seo_title), 
                        'page': str(0)})
    elif self.level == 1:
        return ('category_list', (), {
                        'cat': str(self.seo_title)})
```

The problem happens when the model have the (level == 2) and in my view there is nothing generated...

As when I ask for the get_absolute_url, it should return the url using the first url pattern.

Comment: You should probably make your edit into an answer and accept it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WRONG:**

```
  url(r'^(P<cat>.*)/(?P<sub_cat>.*)/(?P<page>\d*)/$',
```

**WHY:**

missing the `?` before `P<cat>.*`.

**RIGHT:**

```
  url(r'^(?P<cat>.*)/(?P<sub_cat>.*)/(?P<page>\d*)/$',
```